# Molar mass question

Tags: mole

Molar mass of oxygen is 16g/mol , but O2 is 32g/mol , it is shows that 32 gram per 1 mol ,but if we add 1 mol oxygen and one mol of oxygen , shouldn't it be 32 gram per 2 mol for dioxygen ?

it doesn't make sense to me , it is like 2candies/dollar + 2candies/dollar = 4candies/dollar

And we pay a dollar for 4 candies , shouldn't it be 2 dollars for 4 candies ?

Maybe this is a stupid question but i need an explanation

Comment: You will need to add some context to explain why that first equation makes any sense at all. Without that it makes no sense to start with.

Comment: One oxygen atom plus one oxygen atom yields one dioxygen molecule, so 1 + 1 = 1? That is at the root of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two layers to this question. The first is purely mathematical, and from the mathematical point of view, units are to be treated the same as any other number or variable. That is, they follow the same rules as plain old numbers $1$ or some unknown variable $x$. Thus, purely from a mathematical point of view,

$$\pu{23 g/mol} + \pu{23 g/mol} = \pu{46 g/mol},$$

exactly like how one might write $23x + 23x = 46x$ in an algebra course. This is not all that interesting. The more interesting part is the *physical interpretation* of this equation. Let's start with a scenario in which you can't quite write this.

The molar mass of a substance—let's say the molar mass of $\ce{Na}$, which is $\pu{23 g/mol}$—is an [*intensive* property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties). What that means is that the molar mass doesn't depend on the size of the system. So let's say you have two lumps of sodium, and you combine them into one big lump. The molar mass of sodium doesn't change when you do this: the molar mass of sodium is $\pu{23 g/mol}$, regardless of how big the lump is.

This is pretty analogous to your price of candies analogy. Suppose each small lump of sodium was $\pu{1 mol}$ exactly: that would mean each lump weighs $\pu{23 g}$. Then if you add them up, the total mass is $\pu{46 g}$, but you have a total of $\pu{2 mol}$, which gives you the same old $\pu{23 g/mol}$ at the end.

**But**, it is not appropriate to write this as $\pu{23 g/mol} + \pu{23 g/mol} = \pu{23 g/mol}$. The real calculation that we did above should be expressed as this, where $M$ indicates molar mass, $m$ indicates mass, and $n$ indicates amount of substance (which is the proper term for "number of moles"). Since $M = m/n$, we have that

$$\begin{align}
M(\text{big lump)} &= \frac{m(\text{big lump)}}{n(\text{big lump})} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{m(\text{small lump 1}) + m(\text{small lump 2})}{n(\text{small lump 1}) + n(\text{small lump 2})}  \\[8pt]
&\color{red}{\neq} \frac{m(\text{small lump 1)}}{n(\text{small lump 1})} + \frac{m(\text{small lump 2)}}{n(\text{small lump 2})} \\[8pt]
&= M(\text{small lump 1}) + M(\text{small lump 2}).
\end{align}$$

Note the inequality sign, which follows simply because $(a + b)/(c + d) \neq (a/c) + (b/d)$. So it is mathematically quite unsound to write that $\pu{23 g/mol} + \pu{23 g/mol} = \pu{23 g/mol}$.

Note that this doesn't mean that you can't add up molar masses. From a *mathematical* point of view, it is perfectly valid to do so. The problem lies not with the maths, but with its applicability to the *physical* problem at hand.

---

The situation in which we want to add up molar masses is a completely different one, and it occurs when you are trying to calculate the molar mass of a molecule. Let's say, NaCl.* Then, we can sort of write the following; and the "sort of" qualifier will become clearer later.

$$\begin{align}
M(\ce{NaCl}) &= M(\ce{Na}) + M(\ce{Cl}) \\
&= \pu{23 g/mol} + \pu{35.5 g/mol} \\
&= \pu{58.5 g/mol}.
\end{align}$$

Now, the reason why this works goes back to the maths earlier. Let's say, just like before, we have two small lumps, each containing $\pu{1 mol}$: but the first lump is sodium, and the second lump is chlorine. (This is all hypothetical, of course.) And then you combine them into one big lump of $\ce{NaCl}$. What is the molar mass of $\ce{NaCl}$? We have:

$$\begin{align}
M(\ce{NaCl}) &= \frac{m(\ce{NaCl})}{n(\ce{NaCl})}.
\end{align}$$

The numerator *can* be decomposed into $m(\ce{Na}) + m(\ce{Cl}) = \pu{58.5 g}$, because the mass of two things is just the sum of those two things. **But**, the denominator *cannot* be decomposed into $n(\ce{Na}) + n(\ce{Cl})$, because $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{Na}$ plus $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{Cl}$ gives you *not* $2$, but only $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{NaCl}$!

Ergo, we have $n(\ce{NaCl}) = \pu{1 mol}$, and so:

$$\begin{align}
M(\ce{NaCl}) &= \frac{m(\ce{Na}) + m(\ce{Cl})}{\pu{1 mol}} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{m(\ce{Na})}{\pu{1 mol}} + \frac{m(\ce{Cl})}{\pu{1 mol}} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{m(\ce{Na})}{n(\ce{Na})} + \frac{m(\ce{Cl})}{n(\ce{Cl})} \\[8pt]
&= M(\ce{Na}) + M(\ce{Cl}).
\end{align}$$

Note that this time we can split up the fraction into two, because $(a + b)/c = (a/c) + (b/c)$. Aha, so that's the origin of this equation. But note that we didn't *purely* do mathematics to get to this point: we also invoked our knowledge about moles, in that $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{Na}$ plus $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{Cl}$ is equal to $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{NaCl}$. We then used that to simplify our original equation, so that at the end of the day we could write

$$M(\ce{NaCl}) = M(\ce{Na}) + M(\ce{Cl}).$$

This can of course be generalised to molecules with more than 2 atoms. So the validity of this final equation we have here, *rests upon the fact that 1 mole of every component adds up to give you 1 mole of the composite system*.

---

* Yes, yes, $\ce{NaCl}$ isn't a molecule. I know that.